# Change of transmission oil

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission

automatic transmission My service manual states that the fluid to use is Dexron 11 .My local garage mechanic used ATF 111 is this ok?

Comment: It would help if you specified more information about the particular make and model of car about which you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean they used Dexron III instead of Dexron II?

Answer (score 3):

If you are saying that they used Dexron III instead of Dexron II, that is completely okay. They are not interchangeable, since Dexron II should not be used in a transmission that calls for Dexron III or something higher. Dexron III exceeds the properties of Dexron II.

In fact, the original GM ATFs have been [superseded by Dexron III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEXRON#Dexron-III).